# Libsox + portaudio

Tags: c++, audio, portaudio

This time im just asking, how can I stream a song, with portaudio and libsox?

I see a documentation of how to do it with libaudiodecoder, but Now i want to know, if it's possible to do it with libsox.

Thank you very much!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well im on the callback function, doing this:
sox_read(static_cast<sox_frame_t*>(userData),static_cast<sox_sample_t*>(outputBuffer),framesPerBuffer);